# Reading xml or json ...multiple line into single string

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read json or xml file in pyspark.lf my  file is split in multiple line in sc.textFIle(json or xml)
Input

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }
    ]
}
```

Its in multiple line

Output

```
{"employees:[{"firstName:"John",......]}
```

Every think in one string or one line..
In pyspark

Please help me I am new to spark

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the dictionary file (I'm not familiar with PySpark, but superficially, it seems you do) you can use a standard JSON library to "pretty print" it:

```
>>> import json
>>> my_dict = {'4': 5, '6': 7}
>>> print json.dumps(my_dict, sort_keys=True,
...                  indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Thanks Alexander  what to know in pyspark how it works?